# Why the basic authentification gives always error 403 with restTemplate?

Tags: rest, spring-boot, spring-security, activemq-classic, resttemplate

I tried multiple ways to call a get url via RestTemplate in spring boot project to get a json, but every time i got the following 403 error:

```
  <200,{"request":{"mbean":"org.apache.activemq.artemis:address=%22my.queue.demo%22,broker=%22141.110.112.13%22,component=addresses,queue=%22my.queue.demo%22,routing-type=%22anycast%22,subcomponent=queues","attribute":"MessageCount","type":"read"},"error_type":"java.lang.Exception","error":"java.lang.Exception
 : Reading attribute MessageCount is forbidden for MBean
 org.apache.activemq.artemis:address=%22my.queue.demo%22,broker=%22141.110.112.13%22,component=addresses,queue=%22my.queue.demo%22,routing-type=%22anycast%22,subcomponent=queues","status":403},[Date:"Wed,
 12 Jun 2019 12:56:22 GMT", Cache-Control:"no-cache",
 Pragma:"no-cache", Access-Control-Allow-Origin:"*",
 X-Frame-Options:"SAMEORIGIN", X-XSS-Protection:"1",
 Content-Type:"text/plain;charset=utf-8", Expires:"Wed, 12 Jun 2019
 11:56:22 GMT", Transfer-Encoding:"chunked"]>
```

This is the url that i try to call:

```
http://10.185.148.153:1495/console/jolokia/read/org.apache.activemq.artemis:broker=%22141.110.112.13%22,component=addresses,address=%22my.queue.demo%22,subcomponent=queues,routing-type=%22anycast%22,queue=%22my.queue.demo%22/MessageCount
```

When i use Postman with basic authentification (user= test, pass =test) it works find but not with Resttemplate.

Here is my config class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class StartWebApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(StartWebApplication.class, args);
    }
}

@Configuration
class Appconfig{
    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        return new RestTemplate();
    }
}
```

My confroller:

```
...
@Autowired
private RestTemplate restTemplate;

....
restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, createHeaders("test", "test"), String.class)
....
HttpEntity createHeaders(String username, String password) {
        byte[] token = Base64.getEncoder().encode(
                (username + ":" + password).getBytes());
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add("Authorization", "Basic " + new String(token));
        HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<>(headers);
        return request;
    }
}
```

Comment: What version of Spring are you using? I ask because 5.1 introduced a setter method, HttpHeaders#setBasicAuth, that you might find useful.

Comment: I've treid that too but i got the same error

Answer (score 1):

With `RestTemplate`, you can avoid some of the `Base64` boilerplate with:

```
@Bean
RestTemplate rest() {
    RestTemplate rest = new RestTemplate();
    rest.getInterceptors().add(new BasicAuthenticationInterceptor("test", "test"));
    return rest;
}
```

Then you can simply do:

```
rest.getForObject(url, String.class);
```

Not sure if the problem is something in your Base64-ing of the username and password, but doing this would eliminate that as a possibility.

Comment: The type BasicAuthorizationInterceptor is deprecated, but i've treid it also however i got the same 403 error !

Comment: Whoops, I meant BasicAuthenticationInterceptor. I've updated the answer.

Comment: So, probably something else is going on then. Can you confirm somehow that the creds are, indeed, getting added to the request? And can you compare the Authorization header sent by postman to the one sent from your application?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try:

```
String auth = username + ":" + password;
byte[] encodedAuth = Base64.encodeBase64(auth.getBytes(Charset.forName("US-ASCII")));
headers.add("Authorization", "Basic " + new String(encodedAuth));
```

Comment: I've also tried that solution but i got the same message error !

Answer (score -1):

You can try this solution:

1/ Your username/password is incorrect:

Configure J4pClient client using:

```
J4pClient 
    .url(JOLOKIA_URL) 
    .user(USERNAME) 
    .password(PASSWORD) 
    .authenticator(new BasicAuthenticator().preemptive()) 
    .build();
```

pom.xml sample:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jolokia</groupId>
    <artifactId>jolokia-client-java</artifactId>
    <version>${jolokia-client-java.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

2/ JMS Broker does not allow you to access given attribute or CORS issues:

See here: https://jolokia.org/reference/html/security.html how to configure jolokia. E.g. configure etc/jolokia-access.xml for AcviveMQ Artemis.

Comment: The user is using Spring with `RestTemplate` suggesting to drop that and use something else isn't really a solution to the problem.

Comment: @M.Deinum You're right. Maybe someone else will find it helpful.